# How to copy a TF hub saved model architecture?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

I want to create a copy of the [ESRGAN TF hub saved model](https://tfhub.dev/captain-pool/esrgan-tf2/1) architecture.

The reason is directly loading it with tf.saved_model.load() doesn't work with cloud TPUs and and I don't have access to Google Cloud buckets.

I tried to do create a Keras Sequential model and then create a copy of it and save the copy in .h5 format

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([Input(shape=(32,32,3)),
        hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/captain-pool/esrgan-tf2/1", trainable=False)])
model_copy = keras.models.clone_model(model)
model_copy.set_weights(model.get_weights())
model_copy.save("model.h5")
```

But when I load the saved model it still gets the model architecture from tfhub.dev site which is what i want to overcome.
Also the tfhub model files can be downloaded locally. But loading them from the locally downloaded files will also not work on the cloud TPU.

The only way that works is to save the model architecture in an independent .h5 model and then load from it.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate what the use case is? Is it fine-tuning using this architecture on Cloud TPUs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TPU with Tensorflow 2.3+ you can load the model from TF Hub using `load_options` argument of hub.KerasLayer. The code will look like this:

```
...
with strategy.scope()
  load_options = tf.saved_model.LoadOptions(experimental_io_device='/job:localhost') layer = 
  hub.KerasLayer(..., load_options=load_options)
```